# EF5 code first ordering nested items

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, subquery

I'm stumbling upon a small issue when retrieving a set of data with Entity Framework 5 Code First. Here's my code:

```
var data = context.Customers
            .Include("Orders")
            .Include("Orders.Items")
            .Include("Orders.Items.Article").ToArray();
foreach (var customer in data)
{
    customer.Orders = customer.Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate).ToArray();
}
```

This works (whoo!). But, I'm trying to get that `foreach` out of there, I want the database engine to remain responsible for processing data. How do I do this?

I've tried this type of join:

```
var data = from customer
           in context.Customers
           select new {
               customer.Id,
               customer.Name,
               // customer.Orders below doesn't have an Include() to include order items
               Orders = customer.Orders.OrderByDescending(b => b.OrderDate)
           };

// Translate anonymous object to actual models
var customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
foreach (var customer in data)
{
    customers.Add(new CustomerModel()
    {
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,
        Orders = customer.Orders.ToArray()
    });
}
```

But, as the comment says, `customer.Orders` doesn't have an `Include()` method to include items and articles belonging to those items. I then tried to get in from the `context` instead of the `customer` object:

`Orders = context.Orders.Include("Items").Where(o => o.Id == customer.Id)`

But this results in a runtime exception that `Include()` cannot be used this way (in nested queries?):

```
Method 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyTests.Models.OrderModel] Include(System.String)' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyTests.Models.OrderModel]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[MyTests.Models.OrdersModel]'
```

Is something like that even possible, nesting it out like that?

**How do I make the database process the data instead of using a `foreach` in my first code block?**

Thanks in advance.

JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
List<CustomerModel> customers =
           (from customer
            in context.Customers
            select new {
                customer.Id,
                customer.Name,
                Orders = customer.Orders
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate)
                    .Select(o => new {
                        Order = o,
                        Items = o.Items
                            .Select(i => new {
                                Item = i,
                                Article = i.Article
                            })
                    })
           })
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(x => new CustomerModel
           {
               Id = x.Id,
               Name = x.Name,
               Orders = x.Orders.Select(o => o.Order).ToArray()
           })
           .ToList();
```

Although `Item` and `Article` in the inner anonymous object are not used they will be loaded and Entity Framework's *relationship fixup* should set the correct navigation properties for `Order.Items` and `Item.Article` - as long as the relationships are not many-to-many and you don't use `AsNoTracking`.

If you want to perform this as a no-tracking query, you basically have to set the navigation properties yourself. It should be possible by moving the following additional `Select` between `AsEnumerable()` and `Select(...)`:

```
           // .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(x => new {
               Id = x.Id,
               Name = x.Name,
               Orders = x.Orders.Select(y => {
                   y.Order.Items = y.Items.Select(z => {
                       z.Item.Article = z.Article;
                       return z.Item;
                   }).ToArray();
                   return y;
               })
           })
           // .Select(x => new CustomerModel ...
```

Comment: Quite nice! It works and it's compiled to one (large and complex) database query. The only thing I noticed was that some objects are duplicated. It's beest explained with an example. This is my JSON when I serialize the results: `[
 {
  $id: "1",
  id: 1,
  name: "Paul",
  orders: [
   {
    $id: "4",
    id: 5,
    customer: {
     $id: "5",
     id: 1,
     name: "Paul",
     orders: [
      {
       $ref: "4"
      }
     ]
    },
    items: []
   }
  ]
 }
];`

Comment: While I expected this JSON: `[
 {
  $id: "1",
  id: 1,
  name: "Paul",
  orders: [
   {
    $id: "4",
    id: 5,
    customer: {
     $ref: "1"
    },
    items: [],
   },
  ]
 }
];`. The $ref and $id's here are the result of a configuration settings for the Web API to prevent circular references: `jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;`. So apparantly the serializer thinks (and probably is right about it) that there are two different objects in the tree. Apart from that, your solution is a solid and works for my application. Kudos ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var os = new DbContext().Orders;

var data = from customer
       in context.Customers
       select new {
           customer.Id,
           customer.Name,

           Orders = os.Include("Items").Include("Items.Article")
               .Where(o => o.CustomerId == id)
               .OrderByDescending(b => b.DatumAangemaakt)
       };
```

Comment: Alas, using your exact code (with the `new DbContext().Orders` part which I found odd), it doesn't work. `Object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery~1[MyTests.Models.OrderModel]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet~1[MyTests.Models.OrderModel]'.`. Tried removing the `OrderByDescending` and the `Where` to see what's causing this, but even simply using `Orders = os` gave the same exception. Also, even it worked, it has the big drawback that I now need to manually convert an anonymous object to `CustomerModel`s.

Comment: @J.P.tenBerge - What about this : `var os = context.Orders.Include("Items").Include("Items.Article").ToList()`, and in your `data` query this: `Orders = os.Where(o => o.CustomerId == id).OrderByDescending(b => b.DatumAangemaakt).AsQueryable()`

Comment: Though I'm currently still having trouble converting it to a proper `List<CustomerModel>` (exception: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyTests.Models.OrderModel'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`), this isn't much different from what I posted in my question. With that code, I'm still doing the sorting in-memory instead of letting the database engine do it.